# How to store money online without a credit card or bank account?

Tags: webapp-rec

I have a blog and I want to receive money from advertisements such as Google Ads. I don't have a credit card or a bank account, so I am looking for a secure online service to store my money. I tried PayPal but they require a bank account.

Hint: I don't need to get the money as cash but I want to use it to buy some things online.

Comment: You can't receive payment from AdSense in Paypal. They don't have much options  for payment http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1316842 and all of them requires a bank account or credit card.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to register a bank account on paypal without needing a credit card. Possibly open an [ING](http://home.ingdirect.com/open/open.asp) checking account.

Comment: Paypal for sure does not require a credit card. You can do just bank account.

Comment: FYI, The ING Direct Electric Orange checking account requires first creating a savings account, which requires having a pre-existing checking account to fund it.

Answer (score 1):

[Moneybookers](http://www.moneybookers.com/app/) is pretty good and reputable.  The thing is, you have to make sure that the app payouts support whatever option you are trying to do.

Comment: ok , but how to receive money in my account  , thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at payoneer.com they release own Debit Master Card. With it you can withdraw moeny from ATM and use it to buy goods online. I use it with odesk and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy a prepaid debit card and then use a moneypak(sic?) voucher to put cash onto the card. Not sure if that's "online" enough for your needs though.